# Conduction problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

I came across the following problem in my textbook today:

> A container of negligible heat capacity contains $1~\rm{kg}$ of water. It is connected by a steel rod of length $10~\rm m$ and area of cross-section $10~\rm{cm}^2$ to a large steam chamber which is maintained at $100~^\circ\rm C\,.$ if initial temperature of water is $0~^\circ\rm C\,,$ find the time after which it becomes $50~^\circ \rm C\,.$ (Neglect heat capacity of steel rod and assume no loss of heat to surroundings) (specific heat of water $= 4180~\rm{J/kg}~^\circ C$)

The first step is to identify exactly what happens during the process and I suspect that I may be stuck in this very step itself. I know that when bodies having unequal temperatures are placed in thermal contact with each other, they will exchange heat energy via conduction (in this case) in an attempt to equalize their temperatures and be in thermal equilibrium with respect to the other body. Therefore, the temperature of *both* objects are changing simultaneously, yes? (As opposed to heat transfer via radiation in which Newton's law of cooling can be applied, and only *one* object changes its temperature; the temperature of the surroundings is assumed to be constant throughout the process.)

Given this, I was wondering what the fallowing equation (for the rate of change of heat transfer b/w two bodies held at different temperatures, placed in thermal contact w/ each other) even gives:

$$\frac Qt = \frac{KA(T_2-T_1)}{d}$$

If this rate itself is changing with time (until it attains steady state), then how to proceed with the problem? I tried this:

> $Q=mC\Delta T$ and $Q/t=(\Delta T)KA/L$
>
> $\implies Q/t=mC\Delta T/t=(\Delta T)KA/L$
>
> Which gives me $mC/t=KA/L$

But clearly, this last equation is wrong, since it tells me that the time taken for heat transfer b/w two objects kept at *any* two temperatures is a constant given by rearranging:

$t=mCL/KA$

What mistake have I made? Please note that I am not asking you to solve the problem for me; I have not understood how to use the concepts and formulae that I have learnt to solve this and request you to please give me a hint/nudge me in the correct direction, by also correcting the mistake that I have made above.

Comment: Have you studied any calculus? Newton's law of cooling is really a differential equation, $\frac{dQ}{dt}=...$.

Comment: Yes, I studied A.P calculus in high school(I have just graduated) and yes, you are right, but this question is a case of heat transfer by conduction, not radiation...

Comment: Who says that Newton's cooling only takes place when there is radiative heat transfer?

Comment: Well, erm, my textbook :/

Comment: Sorry, I am not convinced by your disingenuous claim that you are not asking us to solve the problem for you! You make a feeble attempt to start the problem without drawing a diagram or identifying any assumptions. Then after a few lines you stop calculating and ask what mistake you made - without getting any answer and without saying why you think you have gone wrong! Then you ask for a "nudge" in the right direction. Altogether this seems to me to be too lazy. You are getting into the bad habit of doing a little bit of thinking them asking someone else to sort it out for you.

Comment: If adding the diagram would've made any difference, I will gladly post it. My attempt may seem "feeble" to you but that is as far as I was able to proceed, before I arrived at $mC/t=KA/L$. Clearly, there is a mistake in my understanding of some fundamental concept, because of which I arrived at the wrong step. I look to correct this mistake; if there was any way for me to do so *without* posting the whole question, and my "feeble" attempt at solving it, I would've done it. I'm sorry if you are perceiving my inability to proceed as being "lazy", somehow.

Comment: Please keep in mind that even dedicated beginners like me are bound to get stuck on problems that they have spent a lot of time attempting to solve. I request you to please not discourage us by accusing us of being "lazy". Physics is a difficult subject to master and I'm sure that even you weren't born a genius. Please try to understand that I am interested in correcting the mistake in my understanding and not at all interested in solving this problem in particular. And so, I have asked the answerer to identify my mistake and not to solve the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why you think the eqn is wrong.... The best way of learning is to identify and correct your own mistakes. If your 1st attempt doesn't work, go back to the start and think through the problem step by step, identifying and questioning what assumptions you are making... After your 1st attempt you are posting on PSE asking for help. You found the problem today. You have not been working on it for a long time... I am giving you good advice to help you become a better scientist, not to insult you.

Comment: I didn't exactly find it on the day that I posted this; that's just something I write for every question, even if I had found it sometime in the past. After trying to solve it for nearly 2 hours, I realized that the problem is in my understanding and I hope you realize that without external help, there is absolutely nothing that one can do if understanding of the concept itself is wrong. I solved some other problems on the internet but they were all too easy. I even watched some videos but I was still unable to discern my mistake. So, since I have no friends/teachers to discuss with, I posted.

Comment: Thank you for attempting to give me good advice but I should tell you that your tone is discouraging and doesn't motivate the OP. Please try to ask the OP to edit their question without insulting them, even if you hadn't meant to do so. (Hey, this is just me giving you some advice from the other side!)

Comment: @ChesterMiller So where is Newton's law of cooling applicable? In my textbook, it is given that it is applicable only in the case if heat transfer via radiation...

Comment: No way.  Newton's law of cooling applies primarily to convective external heat transfer.  Also, if the heat transfer is by radiation, then the heat transfer driving force goes as a difference in $T^4$, not a difference in T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the question expects you to take the steam end of the rod to be fixed at 100°C. It uses the phrase *large steam chamber* suggesting it's large enough not to have any significant temperature change as it transfers heat to the water.

In that case the equation for the heat transferred to the water will be:

$$ \frac{dQ}{dt} = A (T_0 - T) \tag{1} $$

where $A$ is some constant that takes into account the conductivity and geometry of the connecting rod, $T_0$ is the (constant) temperature of the hot end and $T$ is the tempoerature of the water.

To make the equation more useful we note that the temperature of the water is related to the heat transferred by:

$$ T - T_i = \frac{Q}{C} $$

where $T_i$ is the initial temperature of the water and $C$ is the specific heat of the water. If we differentiate this we get:

$$ dT = \frac{dQ}{C} $$

And substituting this into equation (1) gives:

$$ \frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{A}{C} (T_0 - T) $$

which you solve by rearranging and integrating:

$$ \int\frac{dT}{T_0 - T} = \int\frac{A}{C} dt $$

Now, you as what happens then the the hot body has a finite heat capacity so it is cooling down while the water is heating up. We need to be a bit more careful about our notation. Let's call the temperature of the hot body $T_{H}$ and the temperature of the cold body $T_{C}$, and the initial temperatures $T_{H0}$ and $T_{C0}$. The specific heats of the hot and cold bodies will be $C_H$ and $C_C$.

Now our equation (1) becomes:

$$ \frac{dQ}{dt} = A (T_H - T_C) \tag{2} $$

where both $T_H$ and $T_C$ change as the heat flows. The values of $T_H$ and $T_C$ are given by:

$$\begin{align}
 T_H &= T_{H0} - \frac{Q}{C_H} \\
 T_C &= T_{C0} + \frac{Q}{C_C}
\end{align}$$

And the cunning trick is to subtract the second equation from the first to get:

$$ T_H - T_C = (T_{H0} - T_{C0}) - Q\left(\frac{1}{C_H} + \frac{1}{C_C}\right) $$

If you now substitute for $T_H - T_C$ in equation (2) you get:

$$ \frac{dQ}{dt} = A \left[(T_{H0} - T_{C0}) - Q\left(\frac{1}{C_H} + \frac{1}{C_C}\right)\right] $$

This looks a bit messy, but it's just the equation:

$$ \frac{dQ}{dt} = D(1 - E\,Q) $$

where $D$ and $E$ are constants containing all the messy stuff. Then the solution is just:

$$ \int\frac{dQ}{1 - E\,Q} = \int D\,dt $$

Comment: Whoa, thanks sir! Also, I was wondering what mistake I made when I  got $mc/t=KA/L$ in my steps. I was looking to integrate at some point but bam! The ∆$T$ 's cancelled.